# What is precisely the logical problem which Karnaugh map solves?

Tags: logic, computer-science, propositional-calculus

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) says:

> The Karnaugh map (KM or K-map) is a method of simplifying Boolean algebra expressions.

In propositional logic, what is precisely the logical problem which Karnaugh map method solves? Specifically, what are the inputs and outputs of K-map method? Specifically

- can K-map simplify all formulas, or just some? What kinds of formulas can K-map simplify?
- Does K-map guarantee that the resulted formula must be logically equivalent to the input formula?
- what (normal) form does K-map simplify a formula into?
- Does K-map guarantee that the resulted formula must be completely in terms of some complete set of connectives? (e.g. any of $\{\neg, \lor\}, \{\neg, \land\}, \{\neg, \lor, \land\},\dots$?
- K-map is said to convert a formula into some minimal or least complicated form. What is the criterion for measuring complexity of a formula?

I have searched around but am still not clear about the logical problem which K-map method solves. I saw  that K-map is mentioned in some digital circuit design books. I also saw someone used K-map to simplify boolean expressions in if-then programming commands/expressions.
But I have not found any mathematical logic books mentioning K-map. Is K-map covered in mathematical logic books?

Thanks.

Comment: One place I've seen it is [**Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Boolean Algebra and Switching Circuits**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0070414602) by Elliott Mendelson (1970), pp. 98-109 & 120-125. Section 4.16 begins (on p. 98) with the following: *There is a pictorial method for obtaining minimal dnf's* [= disjunctive normal forms] *which is convenient for problems involving at most six statement letters.* Mendelson cites [this paper by Karnaugh](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6371932) and [this paper by Veitch](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/609784.609801).

Comment: Thanks. The Karnaugh part of the book is helpful! Mendelson also wrote a logic book, which I haven't read.

Comment: It's not in Mendelson's (much better known) logic book, at least not in the 2nd edition (only edition I have), which is what I would expect. I checked in some other logic books I have (mostly the more elementary texts), and didn't see it mentioned in any of them. A few years ago I got a copy of Mendelson's Schaum's Outline book at a used book store, and just happened to remember seeing the term "Karnaugh map" in it when I glanced at your question about 40 minutes ago, but I haven't read anything there about it (and don't really have time now), so I can't give a useful answer to your questions.